# Loop through an array by set of 4 elements at a time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an long list of number array and I want to loop through the array by 4 elements at a time

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I want to loop through them so I can work with `1-4`, `5-8`, `9-12` like that

Comment: use a for loop where the index is incremented by 4 - and use slice to access 4 elements at a time

Comment: Is the array always going to have a length evenly divisible by 4? If not, you may want to add some bounds checking, otherwise you'll get `undefined` values for anything beyond the number of array items.

Comment: @MattU It's always going to be divisible by 4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a for loop where i increases by 4.

Note: I was working on my answer when  Jaromanda X commented the same thing.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
  console.log("Working with: " + arr.slice(i, i + 4));
}
```

Comment: But how do access each of them inside the for loop? I am not only printing them out

Answer (score 1):

The [lodash `chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk) method does that.

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3);
// => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 and array functions:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

[...Array(Math.ceil(arr.length / 4)).keys()].forEach(i => {
    const [a, b, c, d] = arr.slice(i * 4, (i+1) * 4)
 
    // a, b, c and d are the four elements of this iteration
    console.log(`iteration n°${i}`, a, b, c, d)
})
```

Notice: `Math.ceil` is used to prevent any error if the array length is not divisible by 4

Comment: why are you using .map and not returning anything?

Comment: Good catch @MarkMeyer.

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right, using `forEach` instead of `map` is better here